# Does a druid have to prepare new spells all at once or can he prepare some spells later?

Tags: dnd-5e

When a druid prepares his spells he spends 1 minute per spell level, and to change the list he needs a long rest.

If the druid can prepare at least 6 spells, but he only prepares 4 of them after a long rest, can he prepare two other spells at some other time? Or does he need to prepare them all at once.

Answer (score 12):

#### You can't.

> When you [prepare your spell list], choose a number of druid spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your druid level (minimum of one spell).

(PHB, p. 66) When you prepare your spells, you the number of spells you choose is exactly equal to your druid level + wisdom modifier. There is no option of choosing less spells than that given in the text. Therefore, there are never any free "slots" in your spell list to fill later.

> You can also change your list of prepared spells **when you finish a long rest**. Preparing a new list of druid spells requires [...] at least 1 minute per spell level for each spell on your list.

(PHB p. 66, emphasis mine) Directly after a long rest, you can can prepare a new list, but as per the rules above, you have to choose all of the spells at once.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, but I don't have my books handy to see if the rules are explicitly different for druids and clerics.

Comment: The rules are the same for clerics and druids