# Leveling Druid up to Level 5, do I gain new spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid

Leveling Druid up to Level 5. 
Do I gain new spells?
If so, how many and from which lists may I choose?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to the site! Do you have access to a Player's Guide? If so, which section specifically is causing confusion? I encourage you to take a look at our [faq] and taking the [tour] to learn more about how the site opperates!

Comment: Related: [Does a druid have to prepare new spells all at once or can he prepare some spells later?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62190/does-a-druid-have-to-prepare-new-spells-all-at-once-or-can-he-prepare-some-spell)

Comment: Do you have the players handbook?  If not, at the least you can look at the [spell list at Wizards of the Coast](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DnD_SpellLists_1.01.pdf); see the druid list on pages 2 & 3.  Are you a Moon Druid, or one of the other Circles?  That will change somewhat the spells available to prepare.

Comment: Do you play Adventure League? If not, what source books does your DM use?

Answer (score 4):

## Druids already know every spell they have spell slots to cast. They only need to prepare it.

Reaching 5th level you unlock 3rd level druid spells, which are alot to list. You don't learn any new cantrip.

At 5th level, you don't get ASI, but as your Druid level has increased, you can prepare one more spell than you could before.

You can prepare your new spells when you finish a long rest. Check the rules on the Spellcasting section, under the "Preparing and Casting Spells" subsection in your class (Druid, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Yep!

You get access to third level spells, two level 3 spell slots, and your proficiency bonus increases from +2 to +3. This means your spell save DC and spellcasting modifier increases by 1.