# How do you figure out the max amount of spells that can be prepared as a druid?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, druid

I have a druid character, and I want to find out how many spells I can prepare at any one time.

Comment: To those who closed the question: I'm not sure this is a duplicate; this question asks about _prepared_ spells, whereas that "duplicate" is about spell _slots_.

Comment: @NathanS I concur.

Comment: Related on [Does a druid have to prepare new spells all at once or can he prepare some spells later?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62190/does-a-druid-have-to-prepare-new-spells-all-at-once-or-can-he-prepare-some-spell)

Answer (score 5):

### Wis mod + Druid Level (min of 1)

The Druid "preparing and casting spells" section states:

> *choose a number of druid spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your druid level (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for
>   which you have spell slots.*

How many to example ...

> ...if you are a 3rd-level druid, you have four 1st-­level and two
>   2nd-­level spell slots.  With a Wisdom of 16 {3 + 3}, your list of
>   prepared spells can include six spells of 1st or 2nd level, in any
>   combination.

Source: [dndbeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid) and SRD(V5.1) p. 20.

Comment: To add to this, here's the Druid page for DND Beyond: https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid.  The Spellcasting section contains this and additional info.