# Can a cleric prepare, cast and then prepare again just after a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

To my understanding, a cleric in DnD can prepare their spells after finishing a long rest. Does that means that a player can prepare their spells, cast some of them, and prepare again just after the long rest?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] if you need some guidance in posting questions and answer here! Maybe your confusion stems out from wizard's arcane recovery?

Comment: Thanks Eddy! I’ll take the tour. 
About the question i made a mistake with “short rest”. Should have been long. Also got answered below.

Comment: Are you asking if you can prepare a subset of your prepared spells limit, then prepare more of them later? As is, the sequence of events is unclear; preparing spells, casting spells, and then preparing new ones after a long rest is *normal* (you prepared the prior day, then adventured and cast some spells, then rested, then prepared new spells), unless there is something specific about the timing that you're not being clear on.

Answer (score 12):

#### Clerics prepare their spells after long rests, and it can be done once per 24 hour.

The basic Rules about the [spellcasting feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#PreparingandCastingSpells) for the cleric class tell us (emphasis mine):

> You can change your list of prepared spells when you finish a **long rest**. Preparing a new list of cleric spells requires time spent in prayer and meditation: at least 1 minute per spell level for each spell on your list.

Short and long rests are described in the [Resting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Resting) section of the rules: the main differences are the following.

- Short rests are periods of ... well, resting, they must be at least one hour long, and no strenuous activity is allowed, if one wants to benefit from the effects granted by short rests (see, for example, using Hit Dice for regaining HPs). You can benefit from more than one short rest per 24 hours.
- Long rests are longer periods, at least 8 hours long, where 6 of them are dedicated to sleep and 2 of them to some lighter activity. You can take a long rest *once* per 24 hours, and then benefit from its effect once per 24 hours.

Hence, the above rules tell that a cleric can change the list of their prepared spell once per 24 hours.

#### Wizards' Arcane Recovery feature allows to regain expended spell slots after short rests.

Wizards have a unique ability, called [Arcane Recovery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#ArcaneRecovery), (emphasis mine):

> Once per day when you finish a short rest, **you can choose expended spell slots to recover**.

Note that even if you can take more than one short rest per day, this ability can be used once per day. Moreover, it allows to regain spell slots, one cannot change their prepared spells.

#### Warlocks can regain their slots after shorts or long rests.

The [Pact Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/warlock#PactMagic) feature allows warlocks to restore all the spell slots after a rest, short or long.

Comment: I meant long rest but it slipped on my mind. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Hi - where does it say you can only have one long rest in the PHB?

Comment: @Senmurv in the linked rules, under long rest, one can read "A character can't benefit from more than one long rest in a 24-hour period, and a character must have at least 1 hit point at the start of the rest to gain its benefits."

Comment: @Senmurv The question you linked refers to short rests, not long ones.

Comment: @Eddymage - thanks for adding the quote; I found it now on p. 186 of the PHB :)

Answer (score 4):

#### All your spells are prepared at once.

We’ve had this question before about druids, so rather than reinvent the wheel, I will reproduce [MrLemon’s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/62191/62294) here in full, as it does an excellent job explaining this:

> #### You can't.
>
> > When you [prepare your spell list], choose a number of druid spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your druid level (minimum of one spell).
>
> (PHB, p. 66) When you prepare your spells, you the number of spells you choose is exactly equal to your druid level + wisdom modifier. There is no option of choosing less spells than that given in the text. Therefore, there are never any free "slots" in your spell list to fill later.
>
> > You can also change your list of prepared spells **when you finish a long rest**. Preparing a new list of druid spells requires [...] at least 1 minute per spell level for each spell on your list.
>
> (PHB p. 66, emphasis mine) Directly after a long rest, you can can prepare a new list, but as per the rules above, you have to choose all of the spells at once.

The rules are the same for druids and clerics, so this answer about druids applies to your question about clerics.

Since all your spells are prepared at the same time, you cannot cast any spells between discrete preparation events.

Comment: I meant long rest but it slipped on my mind. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @JoseManuelPalau In that case, do you think the linked question about druids is a suitable duplicate target for your question here?

Comment: No, I don’t think so, my player wanted to prepare, cast and prepare again immediately after a long rest. I understand that linked question as having an empty slot and maybe prepare some spells between encounters. 
Anyway, if you still think is a dupe I don’t have any problems in mark it as such.

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific. If you think it needs more clarification or clarity just mention me.